# How can I redirect a user after login to the current page?

Tags: users

I have a Drupal 8 site. And I have approximately 5 pages in a site.

For example if a user hits login from the contact-us page the user should not redirect anywhere, they should stay on same page. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: See this issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2582797

Answer (score 3):

The way to solve this can be done by adding the `destination` parameter to the login link.

Whenever the user is navigating a page, you update the destination based on the current page.

This can be done by implementing the hook_link_alter as the following:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_link_alter().
 */
function custom_link_alter(&$variables) {
  $routes = [
    'user.login',
    'user.logout',
  ];
  /* @var Drupal\Core\Url $url */
  $url = $variables['url'];

  if (!$url->isExternal() && $url->isRouted() && in_array($url->getRouteName(), $routes)) {
    // Get current path.
    $current = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
    $variables['options']['query']['destination'] = $current;
  }
}
```

This works fine for login and also for logout links. So when user login/logout through menu link he will be redirected to the previous page.

One problem might face you with that is cache, Drupal will start caching the destination value and won't be updated when you move between pages.

You can solve this problem by implementing `hook_preprocess_menu` and add destination as cache contexts.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function custom_preprocess_menu(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['menu_name'] == 'account') {
    $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url.query_args:destination';
    $renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');
    $renderer->addCacheableDependency($variables, \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath());
  }

}
```

Comment: In the last line getPath() returns a string. When you don't provide a cacheable object, addCacheableDependency() adds automatically a cache max-age 0. So your code works because of this fallback, but is not optimal for performance. Such a solution is developed in this issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2582797, but there is much more code involved.